# Check the content of a field populated by javascript with Capybara before submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, capybara

I have a field whcih I am auto populating based on a dropdown on the page. 
i.e. I select task_type and the task_name has task_type populated.

I can't work out how to test this. I basically just want to test what the current content of the field is.

Everything I try seems to be able to find the field but not check the content of it.

```
Then(/^"(.*?)" should contain "(.*?)"$/) do |field, text|
  page.should have_field(field, :text => value)
end
```

I'm assuming I need to do some js trickery to get the info from the browser, but can't seem to work it out.

```
And I should see "Annual Accounts" in "task[name]"
```

Have tried task_name aswell and both fail with

```
  find(field).should have_text(text)
```

With message

```
Unable to find css "task[name]"
```

if I use

```
page.should have_field(field, :text => text)
```

Then they fail with:

```
expected to find field "task_name" with text "Annual Accounts" but there were no matches. Also found "",
```

Comment: If this happens with Javascript: Do you use any Javascript driver for Capybara (like Selenium)? As far as I know Capybara won't process any JS otherwise.

Comment: I don't understand your problem at all: You say it "seems to be able to find the field", but your error message says the opposite: "Unable to find css "task[name]"". Show the relevant code. In your excerpts is no `visit` method, so this cannot work at all. Additionally you can check `puts page.source` for the field. It looks like it is not there, so the problem is not the code shown here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, both of these work: 
Not sure what the difference between them is. 
I also think this does an exact match. If anyone could let me know how to do a "contains" type match that would be really handy.

```
Then(/^I should see "(.*?)" in "(.*?)"$/) do |text, field|
  # page.has_field?(field, :with => text)
  page.should have_field(field, :with => text)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `have_text` helper

```
find(field).should have_text(text)
```

Comment: Unable to find css "task_name"